# How to design a turing machine for a context-free grammar? what are the steps?

Tags: turing-machines, context-free

How to design a Turing machine for a context-free grammar? what are the steps? for example, What are the steps to design a Turing machine for the following grammar with alphabet $\{a,b\}$.

> $S\rightarrow aX\mid b$
>
> $X\rightarrow bS\mid aX\mid \varepsilon$

This is what I come so far for the above example, in the link, any help appreciated.

[image: Turing machine design example]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Parsing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages

Answer (score 2):

You should first construct a PDA for your grammar. You can then use the tape in stead of the stack. When pushing something in the stack, write it on the tape of the TM from left to right. When poping the stack, read the tape then move the head left if necessary.

There is no other change (states and transitions can be the same).